# Is there a function to split rows in the dataframe if one of the column contains more than one keyword?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

My dataset contains the column "High-Level-Keyword(s)" and it contains more than one keywords separated by '\n'. I want to group the data on the basis of these Keywords.

I tried using function unique() but it treats 'Multilangant Systems',  'Multilangant Systems\nMachine Learning' and 'Machine Learning' differently.

I want the output to be like:

Multilangant - 2

Machine Learning -2

but what I'm getting is

Multilangant - 1

Machine Learning - 1

Multilangant\nMachine Learning - 1

Can you suggest some way to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `.split` on the separator, then count.

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

Counter(chain.from_iterable(df["High-Level-Keyword(s)"].str.split('\n')))
#Counter({'Machine Learning': 2, 'Multilangant': 2})
```

Or make it a Series:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.Series(Counter(chain.from_iterable(df["High-Level-Keyword(s)"].str.split('\n'))))
#Multilangant        2
#Machine Learning    2
#dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

is this what you want?

```
import pandas as pd

df= pd.DataFrame({"High-Level-Keyword(s)":["Multilangant Systems","Multilangant Systems\nMachine Learning","Machine Learning"] })

new = df["High-Level-Keyword(s)"].str.split("\n", n=1, expand= True)

df["left"]= new[0]
df["right"]=new[1]
df2 = pd.concat([df["left"], df["right"]])
df2.value_counts()




#Multilangant Systems    2
#Machine Learning        2
#dtype: int64
```